# Dropdown selected index is not working when it is disable attribute is added though JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Drop down is bound dynamically with items.in a requirement the drop down is selected with particular value and being disable.
I have modified the attribute of dropdown as disable through JQuery as bellow

```
 $("#cmbTeamList option[value='2']").attr("selected", "selected");
 $('#cmbTeamList').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

when tried to check the selected value of drop down in server side, the selected index is not working.

```
if (cmbTeamList.SelectedIndex != 0)
   {
    //logic is there

   }
```

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: I believe values of disabled elements don't reach server using usual get/post submit until explicitly send. You can try setting the attribute as **readonly** instead of **disabled**.

Comment: Readonly will work if the situation is for text box. But here it is dropdown list , readonly property will not going to help any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you disable a form element, it is not sent to server. You can store the value of the select into a hidden input instead.

```
$('#hiddenInput').val($('#cmbTeamList').val())
```

Comment: In case of drop down the readonly attribute will not fulfill the requirement.

Comment: @R.B.Satpathy Yes, you can store the value of the select into a hidden input and get the value of it on the server.

Comment: I have tried this way by putting an extra hidden field. But this is not the proper solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `disabled` elements are not included with `GET`/`POST` requests sent to the server.

The alternative is to use the `readonly` attribute. This prevents the user from amending the control on the front end, but means the value is still sent in requests.

The styling of the control does not change though, so you would need to manually grey out the control using CSS to make it obvious that it cannot be amended.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled form elements are not send to the server. You could create an onsubmit handler to the form that enables all elements just before the form is submitted.